# Xively: Unauthorized when getting data

Tags: android, unauthorized, xively

I'm trying to make an app using the xively api. The thing is, I can't get the information because I get the "Unauthorized" error. I even made the data public, and waited 12hrs now, but still same problem. I can log into my account through my web browser but not through the app.

How can I log in to the service IN my app so I can fetch the information?

I'm programming in Android. 
Here is a public test device which is supposed to be "public":
https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1635144724

Edit: It seems like I need an api key which i do have however, I don't know where or how to use it. Sorry, but I'm new to API world.

Thanks a lot in Advance!
-Celina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after a many hours, I found out that I needed to set a header in my application. 
I had to use:

httpGet.setHeader("X-ApiKey","YourApiKey");

-Celina